# copy paste dropdown data from excel to angular material table (or import excel) and convert it to dropdown

Tags: html, angular, excel, typescript, angular-material

I was trying to enhance the following example to support the dropdown values in the angular material table when the dataset is copy-pasted from excel.

**If Copy/paste doesn't work is there any way I can import the excel which carries my dropdown data?**

There are two ways we can add a data list in excel:

**1. Using the reference range**

[image]

**2. Typing source in the data-validation itself.**

[image]

I do have the following example in stackblitz which works with normal copy-paste data.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-copy-paste-table-from-excel

I am looking for help that how I can enhance this program to support the dropdown copy paste from excel to the angular material table.

How I can pass dropdown values to the angular material table?

**Expected Result:**

When copied all datasets given in the below picture, the angular material table should create test1 first value as a dropdown and test2 as a normal dataset.

[image]

I got one solution to make column values to dropdown but I am still looking for solutions to create a dropdown list directly from the range given in the excel.

Comment: In Excel, that dropdown is shown using validations. When you copy data, it copies values it may not copy the validations.
If you want to make the first column a dropdown and the second column as a normal text then that needs to be handled in the mat-table template.

Comment: Do you want to create dropdown using range E3-E5 ? Is user going to copy paste that also?

Comment: @NikhilWalvekar yes(e3-e5)  but it has to be dynamic sometimes in the dropdown, we don't see values in the sheet as a data list sometimes. I have updated the image.

Comment: That's a problem, since when you copy the cells, cell validation is not copied. User can just copy whatever is shown in the cells. That's the reason in my sample code uses existing values to show dropdown.

Comment: @NikhilWalvekar is there any other way we can import excel which carries cell validations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what I have tried:

- Only the first column is dropdown, there has to be some specific condition to identify this.
- Dropdown is created using the used values for the first column (only those which appear in the data).

Here is the link

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-copy-paste-table-from-excel-vbnzal?file=src/app/app.component.html

Since the dropdown in the excel is validations and those are separate from the data it's hard to get those values unless you are using some API to read the excel file.

Comment: Thanks for your help Nikhil. Below are some observations 1) I would like to have a dropdown for only one cell but currently all 3 cells of column 1 are getting dropdown 2) there is an extra row that is getting added at last even I copied 3 columns.

Comment: added images in question

Comment: @atitpatel updated the above example to show dropdown only for the first row.

Comment: perfect but still 2nd issue - extra row is getting added is still appearing... How I can remove that extra row?

Comment: When you split the data from the clipboard, there you can remove that last empty row. You can either remove all empty rows or only the last row if it is empty.

Comment: Thanks, is it possible for you to update the answer with the same?